# Python - How to create a method for validating data from a collection and querying for a value?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

**This is my working code as of now which connects to a Mongo Server and returns a data output**

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps, loads
import urllib.parse
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


def MongoConnection():
    user=os.environ['USER']

    password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(os.environ['PASS'])

    mongo_client = MongoClient(f'mongodb://{user}:{password}@hostname:portname/Database?axxxxxtlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True,connect=False)

    db = mongo_client.get_database("Database")
    collection = db.get_collection("Collection")

    result = collection.find()

    print(result.next())

    result.close()

MongoConnection()
```

From this, what additional code can I write to create a method for validating the data from the database collection?

**An example query that I plan to use is {"AcctEntxxxx"}**

Answer (score 0):

One possible and up-to-date solution is defining a Pydantic model in order to validate the result of the query:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

class AccountEntry(BaseModel):
    EnmtInd: str  # or any other validation by hinting type

def MongoConnection():
    ...
    for document in result:
        try:
            account_entry = AccountEntry(**document)
        except ValidationError as e:
            print(f"Validation Error: {e.json()}")

    result.close()
```